# QStateMachine: Difference between QEvent and Signal?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qstatemachine

I'm currently porting a [small application](http://github.com/redtoad/weewar-monitor) from PyGTK to PySide which sits in your systray and periodically checks a server for updates.

When I initially wrote this, I used a custom state model to represent its behaviour:

[image: Application state model]

- init: initial state
- check: check server for updates
- disconnected: no connection to server (wait for some time to try again)
- error: server reported an error (user needs to check settings before proceeding)
- idle: wait for POLLING INTERVAL seconds before checking again
- quit

I since discovered that Qt has QStateMachine, which seems perfect for this type of structure. However, I was not able to apply the [examples](https://github.com/PySide/Examples/tree/master/examples/state-machine) satisfyingly to my problem!

In particular:

1. In the context of QStateMachine, what is the difference between Signal and QEvent?
2. How do I define a conditional transition, i.e. on error go to... ?
3. Should program logic happen in Transition.onTransition() or in QState.onEnter()?

Any pointers are appreciated muchly!

Comment: What Signal are you talking about: [`SignalEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qstatemachine-signalevent.html#details) or [Signals & Slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/signalsandslots.html)?

Comment: @twil: I was talking about Pyside.QtCore.Signal (as used in [this example](https://github.com/PySide/Examples/blob/master/examples/state-machine/factstates.py))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. `Pyside.QtCore.Signal` is Signals & Slots derivative.

As for your questions

1. I'd say there is no difference in `QEvent` and `Signal` in context of QStateMachine (although `QEvent` and Signals & Slots are totally *different* concepts). Depending on your needs you can trigger transition with `QEvent` or `Signal`. See [`QAbstactTransition`](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractTransition.html) for the list of out of the box transitions:

   > Inherited by: QSignalTransition, QEventTransition,
   >   QMouseEventTransition, QKeyEventTransition
2. Again depending on what happens inside your application your error may be either signal from `QObject` or you can send (post) custom [`QEvent`](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QEvent.html). You'll need to implement your custom `QEvent` and/or custom `QEventTransition` to trigger transition only on *your* events.
3. And again it depends:) Transition is the glue. It has knowledge about source and destination states. So I'd put only preparatory code inside `onTransition()` and state initialization code inside `onEnter()`. Also it seems wrong for me to put code that changes state inside `onTransition()` like in example you've shown:

   ```
   def onTransition(self, e):
       x = e.arguments()[0]
       fac = self.fact.fac
       self.fact.fac = x * fac
       self.fact.x = x - 1
   ```

   but as you can see it works well.

**NB:** If you have iOS experience then [`UIStoryboardSegue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is analogue for transition. Mainly it is used to pass data between [`UIView`'s](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html) i.e. UI states.